# FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xctest

Got this strange error when running a unit test. It only appears when attaching to the process when testing the target by Xcode. Testing the target without attaching debugger works. Running the test by command line tool also works. Any idea about the reason? Thanks!

```
DetailsThe request to open "org.cocoapods.UnitTestHost" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified ("null").
User Info: {
        BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
        FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x2594;
}
--
The operation couldn't be completed. (null)
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: (null)
User Info: {
        BSErrorCodeDescription = Unspecified;
}
--
```

Some related error messages from the console:

```
SpringBoard (SpotlightUI) Reply Error on 0x600000857000:Connection interrupted
runningboardd (RunningBoard) failed to get pid for label UIKitApplication:org.cocoapods.UnitTestHost[6d75][rb-legacy] : No such process (3)
runningboardd (RunningBoard) Failed to start job for application<org.cocoapods.UnitTestHost>: <NSError: 0x7fa02351ca80; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
        RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:org.cocoapods.UnitTestHost[6d75][rb-legacy];
    }
}
runningboardd (RunningBoard) Launchd says label UIKitApplication:org.cocoapods.UnitTestHost[6d75][rb-legacy] has never exited
runningboardd (RunningBoard) Removing job: <RBLaunchdJob: 0x7fa02491a110; UIKitApplication:org.cocoapods.UnitTestHost[6d75][rb-legacy]>
```

Comment: You should probably check your test target and schemes settings. Do you have this error if you create a new unit test target?

Comment: yes, it's a new unit test target created by cocoapods using testspec. Didn't try manually creating one but it should probably be fine. @RomanZakharov

Answer (score 4):

1. Check your scheme settings and make sure all empty settings are unchecked. After doing this restart Xcode and simulator. `Product menu > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Arguments > Environment Variables`
   If there is a checkmark there with an empty field next to it, then uncheck it.
2. Try resetting your simulator

   `sudo rm -rf /private/tmp/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.*`
3. If it doesn't work try to restart the system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't work. Tried to create a new scheme, also tried to add a few items in the environment variables. None of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Mach-O Type** of your **app**.
Usually this error appears when you try to run **Mach-Object** with inappropriate **type** like *Dynamic Library/Bundle/Static Library/Relocatable Object File.*  To solve the issue select *Project -> Build Settings*. Search **Mach-O Type**, change **type** to *Executable.*